# Collecting all paths of DAG

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a directed acyclic graph where each node is represent by a state

```
public class State{
   List<State> ForwardStates;
   string stateName;
}
```

where `ForwardStates` is a list of next states from the current state.

I have two special state

```
State initialState (name=initial)
State finalState (name=final)
```

I wish to find all paths the start from **initial state** to **final state**, and populated in

```
List<List<string>> paths
```

For example given the graph like the following

[image]

`paths` should contain the value
{{"initial","a","final"},{"initial","b","final"}}

How should I achieve this easily in C# without recursion (as the graph might be big)?

Comment: any algorithms course at all will teach you about search algorithms

Comment: look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search for the first one you learn

Comment: if graph is really big, number of possible paths may grow exponentially, and it is possible that paths string would not fit into even disk, much less memory

Comment: Check out this link for a good description of algorithms for processing graphs. Skip down about halfway for DAGs. (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/)

Comment: Maybe you could adapt Dijkstra algorithm to get you done

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm might go like:

- Create a queue of `Tuple<State, List<String>>`.
- Enqueue `{ InitialState, new List<string> { InitialState.Name } }`
- While the queue has any items,

  - Dequeue the first item
  - For all non-final forward states in the dequeued state, enqueue  `{ ForwardState, DequeuedList.ToList().Add(ForwardState.Name) }`
  - If final state is a forward state, add `DequeuedList.ToList().Add(FinalState.Name)` to your output list.

You should end up with an empty queue and a list of lists of strings as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, I also use the suggestion here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535898/1497720
(The key point is **not using a Visited state** during BFS/DFS)

Here is a version using DFS without Visited state

```
 List<List<string>> paths= new List<List<string>>();
            Stack<Tuple<State, List<string>>> working = new Stack<Tuple<State, List<string>>>();
            working.Push(new Tuple<State,
                List<string>>(initialNode,
                new List<string> { initialNode.stateName }));
            do
            {
                Tuple<State, List<string>> curr = working.Pop();


                if (currNexts.stateName == "final")
                {
                    res.Add(curr.Item2);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (State currNext in curr.Item1.ForwardStates)
                    {
                        working.Push(new Tuple<State,
                        List<string>>(rnext, curr.Item2.Union(new[] { rnext.stateName }).ToList()));
                    }
                }
            } while (working.Count != 0);
```