# finding all paths from given graph python

Tags: python, graph, pygraphviz

I need to find all paths from a given graph. I can do that for now however my recursive code is not efficient also my graphs are very complicated. Hence I need a better algorithm. Here is my code so far,

```
def findLeaves(gdict):
    # takes graph and find its leaf nodes
    leaves = []
    for endNode in gdict.iterkeys():
        if not gdict[endNode]:
            leaves.append(endNode)
    return leaves

graphPaths = {}    
def findPaths(gname, gdict, leave, path):
    # finds all noncycle paths
    if not gdict:
        return []
    temp = [node for node in gdict.iterkeys() if leave in gdict[node].keys() and node not in path] 
    if temp:
        for node in temp:
            findPaths(gname, gdict, node, [node] + path) 
    else:
        graphPaths[gname].append(path)   




    # main
    leaves = findLeaves(graph['graph'])
    graphPaths['name'] = []

    seenNodes = []
    for leave in leaves:
        findPaths(graph['name'], graph['graph'], leave, [leave])
```

There is only one starting node, which makes things easier for recursive function. Every leaf needs to arrive there if a leaf is followed in reverse order. Starting node is the one which does not have an incoming edge.

I have lots of graphs so I keep them in dictionary. Keys are the names of graphs. Here is an example for my data:

```
graph['graph']: {
0: {1: {}}, 
1: {2: {}, 3: {}}, 
2: {3: {}}, 
3: {4: {}}, 
4: {5: {}}, 
5: {6: {}}, 
6: {7: {}}, 
7: {6: {}, 5: {}}
}

graph['name'] = nameofthegraph
```

These structure is taken from `pygraphviz`, it simply shows the outgoing edges from any nodes. Keys are the nodes and values are outgoing edges to the nodes. However when I have very complicated graphs as below, this code could not find all paths.

[image]

Is there any better algorithm that you can suggest? Or is there any way to optimize my algorithm for complicated graphs?

Comment: place this problem in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for optimisation and efficiency

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Thanks I did not know that website.  [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/finding-all-paths-from-given-graph-python)

Comment: its ok. you get good review on how to optimise and efficiency there

Comment: Do you mean finding all the paths in a given graph?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you need to find all paths from a given graph ? Which context ?
I ask you this question because as Graph Theory is something very popular in Computing today, there is probably a algorithm which fit exactly your needs...

*For example, if finally you need to compare all paths to found the best one, you probably may be interested in "Shortest path problem" and read: [Find all paths between two graph nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes)*
&  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

About the "optimization" subject, python allow you to use list comprehension, multithreaded and/or subprocess based code.

You may also try to use a "native graph database" (like neo4js), to store your node, and then use some built in methods like: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-finding-paths.html to do the job.

Best regards