# How to create parent child relation in php

Tags: php, mysql

two tables **Location** and **Routes**. Location table contains following fields and values

```
id | name
1  | bangalore
2  | mumbai
3  | kolkatta
4  | delhi
```

Routes table contains following fields and values

```
id | source | desination
1  | 1    | 4
2  | 1    | 2
3  | 1    | 3
4  | 2    | 4
5  | 2    | 3
6  | 3    | 4
```

want to find all possible routes from source to destination like

```
 bangalore-delhi
    bangalore-mumbai-delhi
    bangalore-mumbai-kolkatta-delhi
    bangalore-kolkatta-delhi
```

please help me to achieve this result

Comment: Firstly, rename your column 'from' & 'to' to something else as it's a reserved MySQL keyword.

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes

Comment: This could easily turn into the travelling salesman problem: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=travelling+salesman+problem

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing data from your two tables, you could `LEFT JOIN` columns *source* and *destination* from **Routes** meaning your `INT` values will match up to the Location.name column. Then make sure you order the data by *source* column for so it's easier to sort with PHP later on.

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT locStart.name as start, locFinish.name as finish FROM `routes` 
LEFT JOIN location as locStart
ON routes.source = locStart.id
LEFT JOIN location as locFinish
ON routes.destination = locFinish.id
ORDER BY routes.source
```

**Output:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'start' => ' bangalore',
    'finish' => 'delhi',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'start' => ' bangalore',
    'finish' => 'mumbai',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'start' => ' bangalore',
    'finish' => 'kolkatta',
  ),
  //Etc....
```

Then add your DB results into multidimensional array using the Source name as the key.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$newArr;

foreach ($result as $v) {

    $newArr[$v['start']][] = $v['finish'];
}
```

**Output:**

```
array (
  ' bangalore' => 
  array (
    0 => 'delhi',
    1 => 'mumbai',
    2 => 'kolkatta',
  ),
  'mumbai' => 
  array (
    0 => 'delhi',
    1 => 'kolkatta',
  ),
  'kolkatta' => 
  array (
    0 => 'delhi',
  ),
)
```

For outputting the new array, you can use a recursive function:

```
function recurse($newArr, $key=NULL) {

    if($key !== NULL) {
        foreach ($newArr[$key] as $k=>$v) {
            echo '<li>Destination: ' . $v . '</li>';
        } 

        echo '</ul>';

    } else {

        foreach ($newArr as $k=>$v) {
            echo 'Source: ' . $k . '<br><ul>';
            recurse($newArr, $k);
        }   
    } 
}
```

**Output:**

Source: bangalore

- Destination: delhi
- Destination: mumbai
- Destination: kolkatta

Source: mumbai

- Destination: delhi
- Destination: kolkatta

Source: kolkatta

- Destination: delhi