# All posible paths between 2 nodes in gephi

Tags: gephi

is there any way to find all paths with the maximum length of 2 and less between 2 nodes or 2 modules with filters in gephi?

1)I tried using an intersection on 2 ego networks (each for one node) is it right or am i missing something?

2)how is it possible to find paths between 2 modules? (or getting the ego network of a module)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535898