# Graph: Finding minimum number of nodes, so that every path from a to b crosses at least one of them

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a undirected graph, that has start point node (lets say A) and end point node (B). 
How to find minimum number of nodes so that every path from A to B crosses at least one of them?
P.S. Node A and B does not count.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved efficiently using max flow.

Given a graph G' = (V, E), create a new graph G' = (V', E' where V' = V × {in, out} consists of vertices v<sub>in</sub> and v<sub>out</sub> for each vertex in V, and E' = E<sub>∞</sub> ∪ E<sub>1</sub> where E<sub>∞</sub> = {v<sub>out</sub> → w<sub>in</sub> | (v → w) ∈ E} has an arc for each edge in E, and E<sub>1</sub> = {(v<sub>in</sub> → v<sub>out</sub>) | v ∈ V} has an arc for each vertex in V. The capacity of each arc in E<sub>∞</sub> is infinite, and the capacity of each arc in E<sub>1</sub> is 1. Find a max flow from A<sub>out</sub> to B<sub>in</sub> and the corresponding min cut C. For each arc in E<sub>1</sub> that crosses C, the corresponding vertex should be removed from G.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem would be to find every path from **A** to **B** and then find the minimum set of nodes that is contained in every path. But this will only work for small graphs because both of this problems are **NP-Hard**. So for small graphs (like up to about 1000 nodes maybe) this solution might work in a acceptable time, but for bigger graphs it would probably take much too long.

To find all possible paths from **A** to **B** you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes) or an [implementation here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/).

After you have found all pathes you can handle the pathes as [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) **S** (where **S** is a set of sets) and try to find a new set **T** that contains at least one element of each of the sets in **S**. Like explained in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr) this problem is known as [Hitting-Set-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation) which has some known algorithms for calculating the solution to this problem like [this approximation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-approximation_of_k-hitting_set) (but I didn't find an implementation of the algorithm).