# Converting adjacency matrix to LinkedList

Tags: graph, linked-list

I have an adjacency matrix and try to make some calculations between nodes. How can I assign adjacency matrix values to the LinkedList in a loop? How should I assign nodes (is it the same assigning ArrayList or should I keep attention the queue)?

```
    for(int i=0; i<k; k++){
        for(int j=0; j<l; l++){
            //I need to iterate linkedlist here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use an array of a LinkedList

```
    static class BreadthFirstPaths {

        private static BreadthFirstPaths dfs;

        private boolean[] marked;
        private int[] edgeTo;
        private int[] distTo;

        public synchronized static boolean checkPaths(LinkedList<Integer>[] graph, int source, int dest, int vertex) {
            if (dfs == null) {
                dfs = new BreadthFirstPaths(graph, source);
            }
            Deque<Integer> pathTo = dfs.pathTo(dest);
            return pathTo.contains(vertex);
        }

        public BreadthFirstPaths(LinkedList<Integer>[] graph, int source) {
            marked = new boolean[graph.length];
            distTo = new int[graph.length];
            edgeTo = new int[graph.length];
            for (int v = 0; v < graph.length; v++) {
                distTo[v] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            bfs(graph, source);
        }

        private void bfs(LinkedList<Integer>[] graph, int source) {
            ArrayDeque<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();

            distTo[source] = 0;
            marked[source] = true;
            q.add(source);
            while (!q.isEmpty()) {
                int v = q.poll();
                for (int w : graph[v]) {
                    if (!marked[w]) {
                        edgeTo[w] = v;
                        distTo[w] = distTo[v] + 1;
                        marked[w] = true;
                        q.add(w);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Deque<Integer> pathTo(int v) {
            Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
            int n;
            for (n = v; distTo[n] != 0; n = edgeTo[n])
                stack.add(n);
            stack.add(n);
            return stack;
        }

        public boolean hasPathTo(int v) {
            return marked[v];
        }

        public int distTo(int v) {
            return distTo[v];
        }
    }
```

, `main` function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        int m = 10;
        int[][] matrix = new int[m][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(matrix[i], -1);
        }

        matrix[0][0] = 1;

        matrix[1][0] = 0;
        matrix[1][1] = 2;
        matrix[1][2] = 6;

        matrix[2][0] = 1;
        matrix[2][1] = 3;
        matrix[2][2] = 4;
        matrix[2][3] = 9;

        matrix[3][0] = 2;

        matrix[4][0] = 2;
        matrix[4][1] = 5;

        matrix[5][0] = 4;

        matrix[6][0] = 1;
        matrix[6][1] = 7;
        matrix[6][2] = 8;

        matrix[7][0] = 6;

        matrix[8][0] = 6;

        matrix[9][0] = 2;

        LinkedList<Integer>[] graph = new LinkedList[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            graph[i] = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] != -1)
                    graph[i].add(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

        BreadthFirstPaths dfs = new BreadthFirstPaths(graph, 5);
        Deque<Integer> stack = dfs.pathTo(7);
        // System.out.println(stack.contains(3)); Another way to check if vertex in path from source 5 and dest 7
        System.out.println(BreadthFirstPaths.checkPaths(graph, 5, 7, 2)); 
    }
```

, output

```
7 6 1 2 4 5
true
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215872/discussion-on-answer-by-sc0der-converting-adjacency-matrix-to-linkedlist).

Answer (score 0):

Your adjacency matrix is `n x n` that means you have `n` vertices. So your length of adjacency list is `n`.

You just need to create an `ArrayList` of lists. You don't need a `LinkedList`. The `LinkedList` has a complexity of `O(n)` for its `get` operation which will be used quite often later after you build the adjacency list. For `ArrayList` it is `O(1)`.

To build an adjacency list you need to do as below:

```
List<List<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<>();
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) //add a list to each vertex
     adjList.add( new ArrayList<>() );
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
       if (adj_matrix[i][j] == 1 ) { //if the value is 1 then only an edge exists.
          adjList.get(i).add(j);
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: What about`getFirst()` and `getLast` methods that I can use source and destination vertex?

Comment: what do you mean by `source` and `destination` vertex ? Please clarify. In order to find a path between two vertices it doesn't suffice to just look in one list of edges. You need to construct a graph and apply some path finding algorithm probably like a depth first search

Comment: Yes, of course I build the logic. The problem with the adjacency matrix is that: I cannot distinguish the vertex that are not in the destination path. For this reason I cannot exclude them when calculating path distance :( If you suggest adj matrix I can get your recommendation to try it instead of lists.

Comment: On the other hand, source is starting vertex and dest is end vertex indicating two nodes in my question.

Comment: Is it possible to combine all possible paths from this list? I get the first index, but cannot iterate all the possible paths. Any idea?

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes) to give you an idea of how to compute all paths between any two nodes in a graph.

Comment: Many thanks, but I had look at that page before asking the question. However, I am not sure which answer is suitable for me. I need to build a path from start point to end point (source & destination) by excluding the vertices that are not on the destination path. Any idea?