# How to optimize this to output all possible cycles in a tree data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, rust, graph

I have working code that gives the desired output but it's really slow (even in release mode) and eventually runs out of system memory with just 100 `Pair` structs.

Below is only a sample of `Pair` struct used, in production, it is more like 70,000..

```
fn main() {
    let pair1 = Pair { pair_id: "abc1", p1: "x1", p2: "x2" };
    let pair2 = Pair { pair_id: "abc2", p1: "x1", p2: "x3" };
    let pair3 = Pair { pair_id: "abc3", p1: "x4", p2: "x2" };
    let pair4 = Pair { pair_id: "abc4", p1: "x2", p2: "x1" };
    let pair5 = Pair { pair_id: "abc5", p1: "x4", p2: "x1" };
    let vec = vec![pair1, pair2, pair3, pair4, pair5];
    let input = process(&vec);
    let mut output= vec![vec![]];
    let current_path = vec![];
    traverse("x1", "x1", &input, current_path, &mut output);
    println!("{:#?}", output);
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Pair<'a> {
    pair_id: &'a str,
    p1: &'a str,
    p2: &'a str,
}

fn process<'a>(pairs: &'a Vec<Pair<'_>>) -> HashMap<&'a str, Vec<&'a Pair<'a>>> {
    let mut res: HashMap<&'a str, Vec<&'a Pair<'a>>> = HashMap::new();
    for pair in pairs {
        res.entry(pair.p1).or_default().push(pair);
        res.entry(pair.p2).or_default().push(pair);
    }
    res
}

fn traverse<'a>(start: &str, next: &str, input: &HashMap<&str, Vec<&'a Pair<'a>>>, current_path: Vec<&'a Pair<'a>>, output: &mut Vec<Vec<&'a Pair<'a>>>) {
    if current_path.len() > 1 && start == next {
        output.push(current_path);
    } else {
        let iter = input.get(next)
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .filter(|e | !current_path.contains(e));
        for i in iter {
            let mut new_path = current_path.clone();
            let next_pair = if i.p1 == next { i.p2 } else { i.p1 };
            new_path.push(i);
            traverse(start, next_pair, input, new_path, output);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd1eaf2eb4454c9d821c45570069e3f1)

One way to improve speed is to limit the depth of which the function traverses, but I am sure there are other ways I am missing.

**Expected Output**

A vector of pair connections starting from a p1 or p2 ID.

*Example:*

Below the starting ID is `x1`. The function finds all of the `Pair`s with ID `x1` for either `p1` or `p2`.

Then using the opposite p1/p2 ID of that pair it searches all of the other pairs where that ID exists in either `p1` or `p2`.

The process repeats until a `Pair` is found with the starting ID (`x1`). Also the `Pair` structs must be unique.

```
[[
  Pair {
    pair_id: "abc1",
    p1: "x1",
    p2: "x2",
  },
  Pair {
    pair_id: "abc3",
    p1: "x4",
    p2: "x2",
  },
  Pair {
    pair_id: "abc5",
    p1: "x4",
    p2: "x1",
  },
]...]
```

Comment: What is the goal of your code?

Comment: @Aiden4 To output an ordered vector of connecting Pairs based on a starting p1 or p2 ID

Comment: You do realize that the number of solutions is _huge_. I'm not surprised that you run out of memory, if anything I'm surprised that you were able to get to 100 pairs before running out…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all paths between two graph nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes)

Comment: @Jmb would you say putting a limit on the depth would be the way to go? Thanks for your input.

Comment: @hkBst I was playing around with petgraph today which has that algorithm. I will check it out some more. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just collect all edges that can lead from source to destination? The amount of memory is then guaranteed to be finite and I can imagine how the algorithm would work.

Comment: @JakubDóka what do you edges look like? A vec of pair_ids? Thanks

Comment: Putting a limit on the depth means you will not get all the possible paths. So what do you really need? Any single path? The shortest path? A reasonably short path even if it's not the absolute shortest? A few alternative paths?

Comment: @Jmb ideally all paths, but if that is going to not work due to memory constraints then I guess a depth limit would be needed, something like all paths up to 5 nodes with start and end nodes having the starting ID in both. I really feel the memory constraints are due to the recursive function calls rather than the output vector itself.

Comment: When in doubt, measure. Can you print `output.iter().map (|v| v.len()).sum::<usize>()` and `output.len()` for the largest `Pair` count that works?

Comment: @James please can you share sample of 1000 pairs of graph edges