# Get all possible links between two strings

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given a list of couple of character

```
["A-B", "C-D", "E-F", "B-C", "A-E", "A-F", "F-C"]
```

How do I find all the direct links between two character?
For instance, let's say that the input of the algorithm is the list above and i want to find the connection between "A-C", the desired output is:

```
["A-B-C", "A-E-F-C"]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but what about A-F-C?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes